# Using DS.model or Ember.model or Ember.Object when defining a model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, javascript-framework, ember-model

This screencast : http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/getting-started-with-ember-model used `Ember.model` to create a person model like this:

```
App.Person = Ember.Model.extend({
    name : Ember.attr()
})
```

The [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_classes-and-instances) give this example using `Ember.Object`

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    say : function(thing) {
        alert(thing);
    }
});
```

Further, under [defining models](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-models) section this example is given which uses `DS.model`

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  birthday: DS.attr('date'),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

What is the difference between these three and when to use which?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Ember.Object - *[mother of all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_all)*

As stated in this very illustrative [article](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) on Ember.Object:

> Almost every object in Ember.js is derived from a common object: Ember.Object. This object is used as the basis for views, controllers, models, and even the application itself.
>
> This simple architectural decision is responsible for much of the consistency across Ember. Because every object has been derived from the same core object, they all share some core capabilities. Every Ember object can observe the properties of other objects, bind their properties to the properties of other objects, specify and update computed properties, and much more.

Now to the differences and when you might use them depending on your use case.

### [Ember.Object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)

- is the [**ember.js**](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js) main class for all Ember objects. It is a subclass of [`Ember.CoreObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html) with the [`Ember.Observable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html) mixin applied.
- you use it to create arbitrary objects, this class is also the foundation to make data binding possible.

### [Ember.Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/blob/master/ember-model.js#L395)

- is used by the [**ember-model**](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) lib and extends [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)
- you use this class to define a model if you use ember-model as your persistence library

### [DS.Model](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L28)

- is used by [**ember-data**](https://github.com/emberjs/data) and it's the ORM system base class which also extends from [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html)
- you use it when you use ember-data as your persistence library to define your models and relationships etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is meant by persistence library or 'data persistence layer' ember keeps talking about?

Comment: @Jatin, when you have a web app in which the user can create/update/delete objects say a post with comments for example, you will soon need to store the state of this objects somewhere (in a database, or using local-storage for example) and for this to happen you would need to write code that does this `persisting` task. Using ember-data or ember-model gives you the fundation for doing this so you will need less code to make your app able to store it states

Comment: @Jatin, `persistence` is synonymous with `saving`.